# jquery css problem in chrome

Tags: css, jquery

First of all, have a look at my div.

```
<div data-category="news" class="element news isotope-item loadimg" style="position: absolute; opacity: 1; -moz-transform: scale(1); left: 20px; top: 20px; height: auto; overflow: visible; width: auto; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
            <div id="1" class="load_cont"></div>
            <p class="number">1</p>
            <div class="element_content">
                  <div class="thumb">
                      <img src="assets/website/news2.jpg" id="myImage">        
                      <img style="display: none;" src="assets/ajax-loader.gif" id="prg1">
                      <div class="date_entry"> 14 may 2011</div>
                      <div class="title news">TEST 1</div>
                  </div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

When I hover over the div, the img, inside thumb, is supposed to disappear and reveal the div's background.

```
.element_content .thumb:hover img {
opacity:.0; /*FF/OPERA/Chrome*/
filter: alpha(opacity=0); /*IE 5-7*/
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
     -moz-transition-duration: 0.1s;
          transition-duration: 0.1s;
}
```

Now comes the jquery part, which is basically, if I click on the div, it would load-in content via ajax.The thing is, the ajax preloader and css changes work pretty well in Firefox but doesn't show up at all in IE and Chrome, unless I remove the ajax part.

```
$('#container').find('.element').click(function(){
                if($(this).hasClass('large')){
               return ;
            }

            var url="item_detail.php?";
            var code=$(this).children().first().attr("id");





         //the portion below this point works well in FF but not in IE or Chrome
            $("#"+code).append("<img style='background-color:transparent;' src='assets/ajax-loader.gif'>"); 
            $("#"+code).css({
            "position":"absolute",
            "top":""+(($("#"+code).parent().height()/2)-27)+"px",
            "left":""+(($("#"+code).parent().width()/2)-27)+"px",
            "z-index":"2",
            });
            var e_code = $("#"+code);
            var e_cont = $('.element_content',this);
            e_cont.css({"opacity":"0.3","filter":"alpha(opacity = 30)","zoom":"1"});
            e_cont.find('.thumb img').css({"opacity":"1","filter":"alpha(opacity = 100)","zoom":"1"});

            var url="item_detail.php?code="+code;





            //If I turn off everything below this point, the preloader appears correctly in chrome and IE, otherwise it seems, the css changes above and the preloader thing don't have any effect in browsers other than firefox.
            var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

            httpRequest.open('POST', url, false);

            httpRequest.send(); // this blocks as request is synchronous
            if (httpRequest.status == 200) {

                e_code.css({
                    "position":"static"
                });
                e_cont.html('');
                e_cont.css({"opacity":"1","filter":"alpha(opacity = 100)","zoom":"1"});

                $previousLargeItem.html(oldhtml);
                $previousLargeItem.css({'height':'auto','width':'auto'});
                var res=httpRequest.responseText;
                $('#'+code).html(res);
            }


      });
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem turned out to be the asynch false thing which froze chrome but for some reason continued to run code in firefox. I solved it by using asynch true and moving the later code in a success event call.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what You exactly want to do.
But try this code, maybe it can help You out:

http://jsbin.com/iserac/11

The transition works. Just make the interval bigger.

```
  .element_content .thumb img {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
       -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
            transition: opacity 0.5s;
  }
  .element_content .thumb:hover img {
    opacity:0; /*FF/OPERA/Chrome*/
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); /*IE 5-7*/

  }
```

Try using jQuery ajax api for ajax calls.